# Failure to load type in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I've got two files in the same directory, an ascx file and an ascx.cs file with a C# class defined inside of it.

This is the code in my .ascx file

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.ascx.cs" 
Inherits="SITE.UI.Controls.Test" %>
```

And this is the code in Test.ascx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace SITE.UI.Controls
{
    public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {


    }
}
```

However whenever I try and build the site I always get this error:

**Error 1   Could not load type 'SITE.UI.Controls.Test'**

I'm sure I must be doing something obviously wrong but after over an hour of thrashing I'm getting nowhere . . .

Comment: Already tried a rebuild of your solution?

Comment: I've tried rebuilding it multiple times, everytime I get this same error

Comment: What happens if you add a new user control, the new user control works?

Comment: What do You mean by 'same directory'. You use web site project? What IDE? Are both files included in project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go into the Web Project properties -> Build settings and change the Output Path to bin\

If that don't work, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598829/parser-error-message-could-not-load-type-testmvcapplication-mvcapplication) post. Here are a lot of solutions for this problem.

Let me know it when it's fixed or not :)

Comment: I editted my answer, try it or check the link. Let me know ;)

Comment: Sorry it took a while for me to get back to you.

The issue was that the designer file wasn't generating, I deleted the template (but copied all of the code first) and created a new one with the same name, apparently that fixed the issue.

Comment: In short, I'm a bit of a n00b with ASP.NET and visual studio, apologies!

Comment: Good luck with it anyway :) It's a pleasure I could help you.

Answer (score 2):

I will tell about my case and what worked for me.
I have a project that worked fine. For no known reason, it got compile/build error.
I have User Controls in a Controls folder.
After dealing with compile error for web handlers, I got a new set of errors for each User control in my Controls folder.
I tried many things include delete the designer file (and create another one empty), the error  I got was Could not load type 'Name.Of.Class' (In directive line #1 <%@ Control %>).

My solution was:
I have added Another parallel control with the name OriginalControlName2.ascx.
Then copied all content from @.ascx to @2.ascx and the same for ascx.cs.
So far so good, no compile error for new page/control.
Then exclude the original file, and change the name of the #2 file to the name of the original.
Error list got down to zero.

With all my experience, I don't know what was the issue, but I got the fix.

**************UPDATE***************

every time when I finish a set of files, it continued to the others.
I find out that the directive <%@ Page/WebHandler/Control/ %> had a CodeBehind attribute.
When I changed it to CodeFile, the Error went off the list.
It is much shorter than adding new file and move all code.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add what worked for me when I was getting the same error. I did an iisreset which resolved the issue.