# Error launching web application after installing it using InstallShield

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2012, web-applications, installshield

When I launch my website from IIS, I get this error:

```
Parser Error Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'MonitoringToolUI.Global'.

Source Error:

Line 1: <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="MonitoringToolUI.Global" Language="C#" %>

Source File: /global.asax Line: 1
```

I found duplicates of this issue, several actually - [Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'TestMvcApplication.MvcApplication'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598829/parser-error-message-could-not-load-type-testmvcapplication-mvcapplication), ["Parser Error Message: Could not load type" in Global.asax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682216/parser-error-message-could-not-load-type-in-global-asax) but none of the solutions given seem to be working for me. The solution which worked for most of them is that they cleaned/rebuilt the solution and it worked. In my case it is an installed website, using a MSI to create the web application in my IIS. I have tried rebuilding my application and reinstalling it, the same issue persists. However this application launches if I run it otherwise so guessing it is an installer issue.

I am using VS2012 and was forced to use InstallShield to deploy my web application. I followed a tutorial(http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cb88b2/simple-steps-to-create-setup-of-website-using-install-shield/) and was able to create my installer. It creates a virtual directory, the content files/project output are copied correctly.

I've checked the .net version, platforms, rebuilt the solution several times. Am not sure what to try next, any suggestions would be helpful.

Note: One of the things I tried, I removed the "inherit" part from the global.asax file and then a similar error was thrown from one of the aspx files. Instead of gloabal, it was a different file name.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you the dlls are inside the bin folder in the virtual directory or your application directory.
For that you should import the Primary Output of your project inside the bin folder
Check out this link:
http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield16helplib/webservices.htm