# How to run a 64 bit web application on a 64bit machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, 64-bit

I have to make a web application as 64 bit [ Since i am using a dll with only 64 bit version exists].
And my machine config is 64 bit machine and in IIS Application pool settings Enable32BItApplications flag is false for all pools.
But when i try to run my MVC3  project i am getting this exception

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load type '_64bitApp.MvcApplication'.

Source Error:

Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="_64bitApp.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>

Source File: /global.asax    Line: 1

Any idea why its happening ? How can i solve it abnd run the project in 64 bit mode

As per suggestions i tried a lot and after changing the output path to Bin\ [instead of Bin\x64\debug ] NOW i am getting the exceptions BadImageFormatException  ConfigurationErrorsException HttpException 64 bit web app

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'TestMvcApplication.MvcApplication'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598829/parser-error-message-could-not-load-type-testmvcapplication-mvcapplication)

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598829/parser-error-message-could-not-load-type-testmvcapplication-mvcapplication

Answer (score 0):

You can force your project to compile in 64bit by changing the Target Platform in the build Options from Any CPU to 64bit

Comment: Yes u did this but after that i am getting the above exception

Comment: did you try the "Any CPU" setting?

Comment: But my project should be 64 bit [ because of limitation that i ma using a 64 bit dll]

Comment: i had problems with dlls when compiling to 64 or 32 bit exclusively, please set to any cpu and try it