# Server Error '/' Application Parser Eror

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, code-behind

I am getting this error

> Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'BombayASP.contactus'.

```
Source Error: 


Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="contactus.aspx.cs" Inherits="BombayASP.contactus" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <!DOCTYPE html>
```

I have followed other steps like :

1. Readded the Ajaxtoolkit by replacing the old one

2. Replacing Codebehind with CodeFile(shouldn't have done but still tried)

3. tried readding the codebehind file 

This used to work fine earlier on same machine, nothing changed as far as I know. 
Its on all of the aspx files ,I have few html but no issues with them.

So please advise.
Thanks

Comment: is your project name "BombayASP".. it says the type is not found... also check.. the name space of code behind and designer files

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem which was solved changing the tag `CodeBehind`for the tag `CodeFile`

Comment: i tried that too but it didnt help. Though thats for website and mine is web app.

Comment: Also have class file there named as 'code.cs' and if I change it to CodeFile then it give this error : Error 14 The type or namespace name 'code' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: did you try what's in there? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598829/parser-error-message-could-not-load-type-testmvcapplication-mvcapplication

Comment: I tried all changing framework, building the website, changing output path dont know how to tried googling but no help.