# Roadkill global.ajax.cs parse error in first run

Tags: roadkill-wiki

Actually I was developed a roadkill wiki app long ago but now try to run it and it faces me with this error.. this makes me crazy :S Here is the error page:

> Parser Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'Roadkill.Core.RoadkillApplication'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="Roadkill.Core.RoadkillApplication" Language="C#" %>
>
> Source File: /global.asax    Line: 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you have not built the app for long time, but try to run it right away after a while.

This post: [Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'TestMvcApplication.MvcApplication'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598829/parser-error-message-could-not-load-type-testmvcapplication-mvcapplication?page=1&tab=active#tab-top) says you'll overcome the issue by building the project from the project folder and right click -> build and it'll get runnable once again.