# I upgraded umbraco version (4.9-4.11.10) everything was fine, but when I build the project I get this error

Tags: umbraco, upgrade, build-process, umbraco4

Could not load type 'Umbraco.Web.UmbracoApplication'. Global.asax problem when I build my project
General Questions
Umbraco 4

Hi everyone ,

I made a upgrade of Umbraco (vers 4.9 - 4.11.10) and I've got error when I build my project. it's

Server Error in '/' Application.

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'Umbraco.Web.UmbracoApplication'.

Source Error: 


Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="Umbraco.Web.UmbracoApplication" Language="C#" %>

Source File: /global.asax    Line: 1
```

The upgrade was fine. I could see the CMS working and also the page, but when I need to change something in the project and I have to build it, I get this error. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of this helped for you?

- [Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'TestMvcApplication.MvcApplication'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598829/parser-error-message-could-not-load-type-testmvcapplication-mvcapplication)
- https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/using-umbraco-7/47382-Issue-Creating-Umbraco-7-project-in-VS-2013
- https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/using-umbraco-7/46809-U7-MVC4-VS2010-Could-not-load-type-UmbracoWebUmbracoApplication

Comment: Hi Sebastiaan, Thanks for your replay. But believe me I tried all of them :-), Probably my problem it's the data structure in the new version, but I'm not sure, The project didn't have global.asax and there is a problem about that. I'm going to try other ways. thanks a lot!

Comment: I think could be a problem in the Core, because the problem is coming when I build the project, before that the upgrade it's fine and the web and the cms work perfect.... To be honest no idea about that! Doing a upgrade from 4.8 to 7 is a crazy idea I KNOW! but it's my work right now... thanks

Comment: Ah I think I know what the problem is, you need to remove global.asax from the root of your site, see `Version 4.8.0 to 4.10.0`: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Getting-Started/Setup/Upgrading/version-specific

Note: I think in v6 or v7 we added global.asax again, but in 4.10/4.11 it can't be there.

Comment: I got it sebastiaan!. My project has different parts and when I build the project the files in my Core didn't change. I just tried to delete all the files in my Core /bin. Build again and I get it!! The problem is my next step, I just read probably there are many incompatibilities with some packages like ucomponents we give maintenance to 23 pages in a UmbracoCms, ... we will have to see how we can change those packages for hard core... it's gonna be difficult work... Thanks again sebastiaan