# MSBuild UsingTask and resolving references

Tags: msbuild, nuget, msbuild-task, yui-compressor

I am using NuGet to pull in `YUICompressor.NET.MSBuild`, which in turn pulls in `YUICompressor.NET` and `EcmaScript.Net`.

It also adds references to all three DLLs in my web project.
I can then add the UsingTask reference like this:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="CssCompressorTask" AssemblyFile="$(SolutionDir)\packages\YUICompressor.NET.MSBuild.2.3.0.0\lib\NET20\Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.Build.MsBuild.dll" />
```

And then use the task to compress my Javascript/CSS in an `AfterBuild` target

However, I don't want to have to reference these DLLs in my web project (as they are not actually part of what I ship)... but when I remove the references, then CssCompressorTask can no longer find the other two dependent DLLs (they are in different folders off the `/packages` folder - it works ok if they are alongside `Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.Build.MsBuild.dll`)

Believe it or not, I have spent hours trying to get the dependencies to resolve:
First I tried to modify `AssemblySearchPaths` to include all the other /packages subfolders, as here:

https://github.com/BenPhegan/NuGetAutoTransitiveDependencies

This didn't work, so I tried to create an inline assembly resolver, as here:

[MSBuild UsingTask Resolve References](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13548851/msbuild-usingtask-resolve-references)

This doesn't work either. At the moment, I am thinking the only choice I have is to get the dependent DLLs alongside the UsingTask dll, one way or another... but this feels like my MSBuild foo is failing me :/

Any ideas much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Currently I am stuck at the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use YUI Compressor.Net MSBuild Task 2.3.0.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665849/how-to-use-yui-compressor-net-msbuild-task-2-3-0-0)

Comment: This post is duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665849/how-to-use-yui-compressor-net-msbuild-task-2-3-0-0 where you can clearly see what its author said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, [v2.4.0.0+](https://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/releases/view/119243) now include the DLLs

Answer (score 0):

I needed my custom task to use the JSON API (NewtonSoft). MSBuild did not load the external dll until I ran `gacutil /i [path to dll]`.

Comment: Glad that worked for you... however, I really don't want to rely on the GAC.