# How to use YUI Compressor.Net MSBuild Task 2.3.0.0

Tags: msbuild, yui-compressor

I have tried searching the web for a solution to this problem but it seems very unclear. It sounds like people are seeing this but the solutions don't seem to work for me.

I have downloaded and installed YUICompressor.NET.MSBuild 2.3.0.0 from NuGet into my project.
I have created an MSBuild target file that closely resembles the example file included and exists as part of my .csproj file so I can run it in the AfterBuild step.

I am getting the following error everytime I try to build my VS project:

```
The "JavaScriptCompressorTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly SolutionDir\packages\YUICompressor.NET.MSBuild.2.3.0.0\lib\NET20\Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.Build.MsBuild.dll. 
Could not load file or assembly 'Yahoo.Yui.Compressor, Version=2.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.
```

My folder structure is as follows:

```
\Solution
    \packages
        YUICompressor.NET.MSBuild.2.3.0.0\lib\NET20\
    \build
        ProjectFile.csproj
```

In the csproj I have:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="CssCompressorTask" AssemblyFile="packages\YUICompressor.NET.MSBuild.2.3.0.0\lib\NET20\Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.Build.MsBuild.dll" />
<UsingTask TaskName="JavaScriptCompressorTask" AssemblyFile="packages\YUICompressor.NET.MSBuild.2.3.0.0\lib\NET20\Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.Build.MsBuild.dll" />
```

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
        <JavaScriptFiles Include="someFile.js" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <JavaScriptCompressorTask SourceFiles="@(JavaScriptFiles)" OutputFile="build\combined.js" DeleteSourceFiles="false" CompressionType="None" ObfuscateJavaScript="false" PreserveAllSemicolons="true" />
    <JavaScriptCompressorTask SourceFiles="@(JavaScriptFiles)" OutputFile="build\combined.min.js" DeleteSourceFiles="false" CompressionType="Standard" />
</Target>
```

Am I missing something? Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: fixed. please read comments, below. Also answered your question, on the codeplex discussion post you created.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to download version 2.3.0.0 directly from codeplex? Then make sure that the Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.Build.MsBuild.dll and Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.dll reside in the same directory. Like this I was able to make it work.

Comment: Nuget package now fixed. v2.4.0.0 updated with the other dll's sitting side-by-side in the folder. Sorry for taking waay too long on this.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since i've played around with the `AfterBuild` .. but how this works is that the the msbuild program is ran from some directory .. and therefore looks for those assembly files **RELATIVE** to where the msbuild is being executed *from*.

I'm not sure if this means the msbuild is being run from `C:\program files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\<whatever...>`

TAKE NOTE: it's the folder/path (aka execution path) where visual studio is running the msbuild command from ... NOT where msbuild exists.

So therefore, it can't find the assemblies.

Try putting in the full path to the assemblies (just to see if that works).

eg. `C:\Projects\Solution\packages\YUICompressor.NET.MSBuild.2.3.0.0\lib\NET20\Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.Build.MsBuild.dll`

If it's running it from the `\solution\bin` directory, then you're in luck! cause then you can do `..\packages\YUICompressor.NET.MSBuild.2.3.0.0\lib\NET20\Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.Build.MsBuild.dll' (the`..`means: from this`bin`directory, go up one level to`solution`then down into`packages`and then down into`YUIComp`... etc.

So the answer to your question is this: Find the location Visual Studio is running the msbuild command from, during an AfterBuild. Maybe put in some code in there to say *'write to file => current path i'm in :P'*

Comment: I tried using the full path but continue to get the same error. It looks as though the issue is in trying to resolve the dependency of the MSBuild task: Yahoo.Yui.Compressor, Version=2.3.0.0. I tried adding it to the same directory as the msbuild file but no luck.

Comment: Downloading the YUI Compressor directly from http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/ got me past this problem. Not sure if the NuGet packages are out of sync but using them as they were installed didn't seem to work. Leaving this open for now just in case someone from YUI Compressor community chimes in.

Comment: I had the same issue. The NuGet package is v2.3.0.0 and didn't work out of the box, even with the Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.dll in the same directory... Downloading the .dlls manually worked though.

Comment: Blech :( I'll need to get onto this and fix it :(

Comment: @Pure.Krome please do fix it. I've just installed 2.3.0.0 via NuGet in VS and tripped up over this. Or at least point it out in your very useful video tutorial on YouTube. It's a great product.

Comment: @vegemite4me I'm trying to repo this .. and .. well .. I'm not really sure how people are trying to use this .. so I can then get a repo, to fix.

Comment: Folks - all fixed with latest nuget v2.4.0.0 updated to nuget. Try dat hot potatoe!