# fixing syntax error in global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i have an asp.net mvc4 application. i have a problem in `Global.asax` file

[image: demo]

the **Global.asax.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace integration_finale
{

    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
}
```

when i launch the application i got this error:

[image: demo2]

translated to english

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>        Analysis error
>        Description: An error occurred during the analysis of a requirement to meet this demand resource. Please see below the details
>   of the error analysis in question and modify your source file
>   appropriately.
>
> Message Parser Error: Could not load type
>   'integration_finale.MvcApplication'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1: <% @ Application Codebehind = "Global.asax.cs" Inherits =
>   "integration_finale.MvcApplication" Language = "C #"%>
>
> Source File: / global.asax Line: 1
>
> Version Information: Microsoft NET Framework Version:. 4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.18056

So what is the issue and how can i fix it?

Comment: have you tried putting a breakpoint in your Application_Start() method?

Comment: yes but i didn't reach the breakpoint !!!

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding the entire solution.

Comment: i tried this, but the same thing :(

Comment: What does that error message say, translated into English?

Comment: @Liam [unlocalize.net](http://unlocalize.com/fr/1226_Cannot-load-type-x0.html): _"Cannot load type 'Type Name'"_.

Comment: OP, do you use IIS express? Do you have another project that uses the same development server URL?

Comment: yes i'm using IIS express and i don't have another appl launched now

Comment: no i think the problem is in the name of application because i commit a fault in the nomation `integration_fianle` then i change it to `integration_finale` in the hole application, but when i check the iis launched application i find the application with `integration_fianle` as name !!!!

Comment: thanks @CodeCaster can you post it as an answer?

Comment: After I deleted the IISExpress folder in my home documents folder, I changed the port number of my app and now it works. Hope it helps. I tried everything else I could find, this did the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error is thrown when IIS Express fails to load any library that contains the requested class, in this case `integration_finale.MvcApplication`. The fact that it can't find the library can have many causes, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005747/could-not-load-type-namespace-global-causing-me-grief), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120329/could-not-load-type-mvcapplication) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682216/parser-error-message-could-not-load-type-in-global-asax) a few are named.

IIS Express adds a whole new layer of confusion to this. The first application you register with IIS Express for a given port, gets its project path registered. When you rename a project or run a new project configured with an earlier-registered port, IIS Express will happily start serving from the wrong directory. This is especially funny when you have identical projects (say, a DEV and a ACC branch, so the library containing a web application with the same name *can* be found), as the things you see in the browser aren't what you expect them to be.

Open your `My Documents\IISExpress\config\appplicationhost.config`, and do a search for the port configured for the web application giving the error. You'll see a section like this:

```
<site name="YourWebsiteName" id="1">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Source\WebsiteProject" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:1234:localhost" />
    </bindings>
</site>
```

Check the application section and verify `physicalPath` is pointing to your current project. Every request to that port is served from that `physicalPath`, given the `virtualDirectory` is met (it is in this and most cases, as there is only one virtual directory, starting at the root of the site).

If you rename a project directory, or have two projects using the same port, stuff breaks with IIS Express. Possible fixes:

- Just change your web project's port used for IIS Express in VS's properties window. This will create a new IIS Express site.
- Click "Create Virtual Directory" button in your project's configuration. This usually works after a rename, but not after copy.
- Modify IIS Express' configuration (of course, make a backup). You can rename the site when required and correct the `physicalPath` of the `virtualDirectory`.