# Breakpoint not enabled in ASP.NET project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, razor

I am running an asp.net project onto a local IIS Express server and none of my breakpoints seem to be active. Ive tried switching to normal IIS but to no avail

I managed to get a breakpoint to hit in `Global.asax.cs` but everything else (such as my `BaseController`) doesnt get hit.

It directs me to my login page (which I am trying to remove, but seemingly cant) yet the Logon function in the AccountController never gets hit either.

I simply get the hollow red circle where the breakpoint is set that tells me my source doesnt match the original version.  Ive tried restarting VS, cleaning the solution, even manually deleting the bin files.

Any ideas?

**Answers to questions**

- Yes I am running debug
- `<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">` is in my web.config
- I have tried running the website in both Chrome and IE after running

Comment: Seems to me the code served up by the URL the project is launching is coming from somewhere else. It could be the `HOSTS` file has been modified? Maybe some DNS was added to support something you'd tested prior?

Comment: Have you checked where the IIS web site configuration points too ? Check also that you're not in release mode

Comment: What `physicalPath` is your `My Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config` pointing to for the `bindingInformation` with the port your project claims to be running on? Is this the same as your project's directory?

Comment: And of course the obligatory "Clean, close VS, delete `bin`, restart VS, rebuild"? Edit: I missed you already did that. What about above comment?

Comment: @CodeCaster aleady tried that numerous times :/

Answer (score 1):

have you wrote in web.config debug = true 
 and check the internet explorer setting is degugging in other is disabled? for internet setting check [internet debug settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z959x58c.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

How about deleting Temporary ASP.NET files?

Located at: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\<version_number>\Temporary ASP.NET Files`

Answer (score 0):

a few things to try:

CLEAN solution then REBUILD

Debug > Attach to process and attach it to the IIS worker process if you are hosting the site in IIS.

Cleaning the temp ASP.NET files

Making sure that the site is built in DEBUG mode - sometimes even setting it into RELEASE mode will not hit the breakpoints as all the symbols are stripped out but even then other factors to consider in this context

Delete all your breakpoints and just add 1 - what happens?

Answer (score 0):

> I simply get the hollow red circle where the breakpoint is set that
>   tells me my source doesnt match the original version.

This may be the clue to what is going wrong. I had this same exact problem just recently, and I had to turn off "Just My Code" as part of the debugging options. To do this, in Visual Studio, go to:

> **Tools > Options > Debugging > General**

and then clear or enable Just My Code. Clean and Rebuild as others have suggested and that should fix your issue with breakpoints. (It did mine, at least.)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue was due to my build directory, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15806252/94278) which made me check and after fixing this it instantly started to work properly!