# Upgrading nopcommerce plugin from 2.7 to 3.4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, plugins, nopcommerce

I am using Nopcommerce 3.40.
but i have one plugin which is in 2.7 so i need to convert it in 3.4.
while converting this plugin all changes is done by my side in version changes of web.config file and .net framework version also.
then also it will return below error while running project in browser.

**"Could not load type 'Nop.Web.MvcApplication'."**

the error image is below.

plz advise.[image]

Comment: duplicate question find solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120329/could-not-load-type-mvcapplication