# Could not load type 'Truesys.Application.Admin.MvcApplication'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, model-view-controller

I have a project known as Truesys.Application.Admin. When i run this project on
visual studio 2015 it shows me an error page like this.

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="Truesys.Application.Admin.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: can anyone help me out with this, i got stuck in this error.

Comment: Unload project then load again please see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120329/error-could-not-load-type-mvcapplication