# I am getting this error in Global.asax Could not load type 'WebApplicationProduction.MvcApplication' in every webapplication in visual studion

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am getting this error in Global.asax

```
Could not load type 'WebApplicationProduction.MvcApplication' for every webapplication I am creating in Visual Studio.
```

Here is the front end.Here I am getting the error.Browser is showing the error here only.

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="WebApplicationProduction.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>
```

Here is the back end that is present before.So please help me to get rid of this.
In the back end I have changed nothing but still it is showing the same error.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace WebApplicationProduction
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What file is your MvcApplication class in? And if you didn't change anything, why did it break? Are you using proper source control?

Comment: I have just opened the Web Application in Visual Studio and do the run.After that I am getting this error.

Comment: That doesn't answer all my questions.

Comment: @Duston every Asp.Net MVC application has that.  That isn't a view, it's his `global.asax`

Comment: The question says this is MVC, but I don't see any MVC code in the question.  That's all Web API.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: «Could not load type MvcApplication»](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120329/error-could-not-load-type-mvcapplication)

Comment: @Duston It's a good idea to clean up your comments when they're obsolete, to reduce confusion. Click the "x" you see when hovering over them.

Comment: Keep in mind that your Global.asax file is not considered "front end" in the context of an ASP.NET application. It's entirely server side. The only front end of a web application is the HTML, CSS, JavaScript etc that run within the browser.

Comment: This error is happening for every MVC application I am opening in Visual Studio